# How to execute sql file using another sql file MSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Im creating database which need few sql scripts. Running them one by one is not effective , so I wanted to create main sql query which will load all files. I tried this :

```
 Declare
 @DBServerName Varchar(100),
 @DBName Varchar(100), 
 @FilePathName Varchar(100),
 @strSql varchar(1000)

 Set @DBServerName='USER-PC'-- Server Name
 Set @DBName='testo' -- DB Name
 Set @FilePathName='some path here'

 Set @strSql= 'sqlcmd -S ' + @DBServerName + ' -d ' + @DBName + ' -i ' +        @FilePathName

 EXEC xp_cmdshell @strSql
```

After executing this, It is showing that my query was executed succesfully but in my database nothing is appearing. Ive seen lot of websites but there is no working answear.

Comment: We need to see some code to know what is being executed and to reproduce. Also, why not incorporate all TSQL statements into one stored procedure?

Comment: I don't think you want xp_cmdshell here.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you want xp_cmdshell here. If you want to execute dynamic SQL you should be using the code below:

```
sp_executesql @strsql;
```